# Webpack - Split chunks by path

Tags: webpack

Looking for some community help with a Webpack plugin, [webpack-split-by-path](https://github.com/BohdanTkachenko/webpack-split-by-path). The plugin currently has a few issues working with other optimization plugins. With that in mind, I attempted to correct said issues and made a [PR](https://github.com/BohdanTkachenko/webpack-split-by-path/pull/19). However, I have noticed that this plugin, with or without my changes, has a serious issue. It cannot support splitting out chunks by paths with more than one configured path/chunk. As I indicate in the PR, it appears to create a circular dependency between the chunks causing neither to be able to load.

For the record, I have tried posting on the Webpack gitter channel to no avail. Any help figuring out how to correct the issue is appreciated. I believe the solution is along the lines of, if I move one module due to the split-by-path, I need to check for and move all of its dependencies. However, doing this seems to be stumping me.